# Python asyncio for triggering event w/o waiting for response

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

Suppose I have an event driven architecture and two functions, named outer and inner. Outer will call inner but outer does not require the response from inner. As soon as the request has been sent to inner, outer can terminate.

Can this be accomplished in Python using asyncio? Is it as simple as not using the `await` keyword?

Ex

```py
async def outer():
    inner()
    return
```

As opposed to

```py
async def outer():
    await inner()
    # not blocked by inner...but no remaining steps to perform
    return
```

Edit, a real example

```py
def inner():
    print('inner started')    
    time.sleep(5)
    print('inner complete')
    
async def outer():
    print('outer started')
    inner()
    print('outer complete')
    

def next_():
    print('next started')
    print('next complete')
```

Scenario one

```py
outer()
next_()

>>>
next started
next complete
/var/folders/p9/b46sgf393ys74l8dsh5fxyc80000gr/T/ipykernel_1113/3300557029.py:16: 
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'outer' was never awaited
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Scenario two

```py
await outer()
next_()
>>>
outer started
inner started
inner complete
outer complete
next started
next complete
```

It would seem that there is not a way to terminate outer once inner has been invoked. Note: Using Jupyter notebook, which might perform async operations anomalously

For anyone wondering, "why does this matter? Just have outer await inner and call next" - consider two serverless functions A and B where if the result of B is not required by A, then A's computational costs are needlessly increased.

Answer (score 1):

`asyncio` coroutines only run in the background when you call `await` *somewhere*. You don't need to `await` on `inner` itself, but `inner` will only run when some other part of your code calls `await` on something else, which gives pending coroutines a chance to execute.

Also:

- Never call `time.sleep` in an `async` coroutine; while the coroutine is sleeping, *nothing else can run*. You need to call `await asyncio.sleep()` instead.

For example:

```
import asyncio

async def inner():
    print('inner started')    
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print('inner complete')
    
async def outer():
    print('outer started')
    asyncio.create_task(inner())
    print('outer complete')

async def main():
    while True:
        await outer()
        await asyncio.sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: In case you didn't see my context about serverless functions, I'm guessing the more practical real world solve is lambda A inserts an entry into DynamoDb, S3, etc and then lambda B is triggered outside the scope & runtime of lambda A (Lambda-S3 trigger, DynamoDb Streams, etc).